# What's best way to resolve race condition in Java Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, race-condition

I develop simple quiz web application on Spring, that implements "Quiz button", on client side players should click the button faster than other to get points. So I have controller method like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pressButton", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processButtonClick(Authentication authentication) {
    //return first player name
}
```

How to check what user clicked that first? How to prevent race condition while db update?

Comment: You can synchronize the method , use java locks or db locks

Comment: As you're using SQL, you could play with transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign your method with `synchronized`, then it will not run simultaneously many times.

Comment: this would work but not if multiple instances of service are deployed.

Comment: true, I was considering it as a toy project, not an architecture issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest go with adding unique constraint for userId and questionId combination in your DB. synchronized will work only if there is only once instance of service, which is rarely there for highly scalable environment. Redis lock is another viable option.